# Update Devise user with association to 'Language' model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Building a Rails app using devise. The user can edit all the information on their profile page (name, description etc.) inside devise/edit.html.erb. The user model has an association to language model. I want the user to be able to pick their own language when editing their profile from a f.select. How do I make this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Edit.html.erb:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :coach_id %>
        <%= f.select(:coach_id, User.where('is_coach = ?', true).pluck(:name, :id), {}, { :class => 'select2 form-control' }) %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control', rows: '5' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :facebook %>
        <%= f.text_field :facebook, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :twitter %>
        <%= f.text_field :twitter, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :image %>
        <%= f.file_field :image, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :header_image %>
        <%= f.file_field :header_image, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit 'Update Settings', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
  t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
  t.boolean  "is_coach",               default: false
  t.text     "description"
  t.string   "image_uid"
  t.string   "header_image_uid"
  t.string   "facebook"
  t.string   "twitter"
  t.boolean  "featured"
  t.integer  "coach_id"
  t.string   "name"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
end

create_table "languages", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string  "language_code"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_languages_on_user_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "languages_users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "language_id"
  t.index ["language_id"], name: "index_languages_users_on_language_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_languages_users_on_user_id", using: :btree
end
```

*User*

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :languages
```

*Language*

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Comment: Do you have predefined languages? I dnt think so though..

Comment: No, I don't have predefined languages. I'm using i18n

Comment: Couldn't you save the language setting on the user and just use your session to set the language?

Comment: Well there are couple of ways i think of providing array to you select option. 1. Seeding data on the go from users, and then querying `Language.pluck(:language_code).uniq`. 2. Create a constant/yml file with the possible codes you support. I would go with 2nd option as it saves me query which can be costly in the long run when u have thousands of rows.

Comment: Just tried to go for @StephenC option and even though it worked it's not consistent with what I do elsewhere on the platform where I use the relation (e.g. camp.language.pluck(:name)) 

I can easily assign a language through Rails_Admin to user - What I don't understand is how I create this relation from editing a devise user?